# xml serialization of third party object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I am trying to serialize third party object which is not marked as serializable and is quite complex object in terms of hierarchy.

Object has some collections, parameterless constructor so is there any way to serialize such object with help of reflection or anything

Comment: Did you try Xml Serialisation (which doesn't *require* any special attributes to work)? did you get some errors?

Comment: Yes when i tried i get following error To be:           XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add() at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy

Comment: sure would be nice to see an example of the objects structure and or xml output that you are trying to serialize the object to.. I bet if you do a google search on this `To be: XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add()` you will find some good reading material

Comment: Yes i get plenty of workarrounds but those are somethign i should add in the code to get rid of this which i can't as its third party object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically; don't do that. Your best bet here would be to create a DTO model - i.e. a **separate** model that looks kinda like the 3rd party model, but which is designed to be suitable for (in this case) serialization. Then just map between the two models.

This will allow you full flexibility to serialize the model, *and* to change things in the future as needed. This approach also scales readily to multiple models (if you need to support different formats that don't have identical layouts, for example; or 2 different versions of the same format).